# Order of Execution of Modifications on Selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3.js, numerous calls to modify aspects on all elements in a given selection can be chained like so:

```
mySelection.attr('someAttribute', function retrieveSomeAttributeValue (d) {
    return d.someValue;
}).style('someCssProperty', function retrieveSomeCssPropertyValue (d) {
    return d.someValue % 2;
});
```

Now, both `retrieveSomeAttributeValue` and `retrieveSomeCssPropertyValue` will be called once for each element in `mySelection`.

However, is their order of execution for any given element also specified? I could not find anything explicit on this in the docs. Concretely: For any given element in `mySelection`, is `retrieveSomeAttributeValue` guaranteed to be called before `retrieveSomeCssPropertyValue` because the `attr` call surrounding the former precedes the `style` call surrounding the latter in the call chain?

In general terms: **Are modification functions such as `attr` and `style` applied in the order they are chained?**

EDIT: As there seems to be some confusion about the scope of my question, I will try to clarify: Obviously, the `attr` function is invoked before the `style` function. But does `attr` apply its changes to each element, and then return the resulting collection, whereupon `style` applies its changes to each element? Or do, for instance, `attr` and `style` somehow add their respective modifications as pending changes on the collection object, to be executed in a possibly different order at a later time?

EDIT2: As this question appears to generate some confusion, please use the comments area to ask for clarification if anything in particular is unclear.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Admittedly, I was one who got very confused by this question which led to my now self-deleted answer. I first assumed you had been asking about JS operator precedence and associativity, an impression you corrected with your first edit. I am still not sure what you are really asking. Taking the question literally the answer is quite simple: No, there is no hidden magic. However, I keep asking myself why you would ask such an obvious thing easily accessible by looking into D3's source code. I reckon there must be more to it. Do you have any suspicion leading to this?

Comment: @altocumulus: For one, I don't consider it an "obvious thing" at all, given how d3.js hides quite some complexity in amazingly simple calls. Other than that, looking at a library's source code is rarely a good way to answer this kind of questions IMHO. Besides the certainly existing chance I might miss something in there, whatever I find only represents the *current* behaviour of the library, without giving any indication whether it is the intended behaviour or just happens to work that way in the current imlementation. What I am looking for is rather some kind of a guarantee from the docs ...

Comment: ... that indicates a certain behaviour with respect to order of execution for chained `attr` calls and similar on a selection.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Always because a call to `attr()`, `style()` , `append()`, `filter()`, .... return a selection that the next call operates on. This selection can be different of the selection the call operates on.

Before the return the callbacks (if defined) are called for every element in the selection. There is no asynchronous stuff happening behind the scenes.

Comment: I think this is not too bad an answer. Maybe I'm just being overly cautious about the "Before the return the callbacks (if defined) are called for every element in the selection." aspect (because I think I've come across other libraries before that specified things like "assigns X to Y and returns" that had some elaborate behind-the-scenes stuff going on that meant that the *actual* assignment did happen only later, during some lazy evaluation after the return). I'll accept this answer for now, but will upvote if I end up accepting another, even better answer, later on.

Comment: maybe you mean the calls made to a `transition`. they can be on the `start`, or `end` event or transition continuation or attribute change in the transition or the callbacks of the force simulation but it would be very strange if the `attr` or `style` methods postpone the assignment/modification on a regular selection. it all depends how the **other** library implements there calls

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to fiddling with the DOM tree D3 tends to be implemented pretty straightforward without having to resort to any kind of hidden magic. Many calls to D3's methods will more or less directly delegate to native DOM interfaces. Methods like `.attr()` and `.style()` are no exception to this general assessment.

Since documentation may hide the inner workings of a library from its reader and user, the best way to assure yourself of the way D3 does this stuff is probably to dig into its source code. As an example let us have a look at [`selection.attr()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr).

According to the docs:

> [*#*](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr) *selection*.**attr**(*name*[, *value*]) [<>](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/attr.js)
>
> […] otherwise, if the value is a function, it is evaluated for each selected element, in order, being passed the current datum (*d*), the current index (*i*), and the current group (*nodes*), with *this* as the current DOM element (*nodes[i]*). The function’s return value is then used to set each element’s attribute.

This describes the method's usage as a setter by providing two arguments to the call: the first being the attribute's name, the second being the callback. The [relevant](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/attr.js#L53-L56) part of the method's [full](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/attr.js) source look like this:

```
return this.each((value == null                          // <== For all nodes in this selection...
    ? (fullname.local ? attrRemoveNS : attrRemove) : (typeof value === "function"
    ? (fullname.local ? attrFunctionNS : attrFunction)   // <== ...set to callbacks return value.
    : (fullname.local ? attrConstantNS : attrConstant)))(fullname, value));
```

Based on how to handle namespaces (`fullname.local`)  it will call the appropriate function `attrFunctionNS` or `attrFunction`. [Both](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/9ffa69f363b5ee9af2171879d798091eab68def0/src/selection/attr.js#L27-L41) of which look quite similar:

```
function attrFunction(name, value) {
  return function() {
    var v = value.apply(this, arguments);       // Evaluate the callback. 
    if (v == null) this.removeAttribute(name);  // Standard method call.
    else this.setAttribute(name, v);            // Standard method call.
  };
}
```

The function returned from this call will execute the callback (referred to by `value`) on its first line. Based on the value returned from that call it will either remove the attribute if that value equals `null` or it will set the attribute's value to the callback's return value. Both these operations make use of the two standard DOM API methods [`Element.removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) or  [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), respectively.

As can easily be seen from these few lines, D3 does not make any use of hidden magic or intrinsic state but directly forwards to native DOM methods. For this same reasion you are guaranteed that your callbacks will get called for every node in the selection in the very same order as they are chained.